# NodeJs GraphQL dynamic query variable

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, express-graphql

https://launchpad.graphql.com/9qvqz3v5r

Here is my graphQL example

If i passed userId:2 as static

```
{
  user(userId:2){
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

I will get output as below

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "firstName": "Joe",
      "lastName": "spin"
    }
  }
}
```

I need same output using dynamic query variable

```
query getUserNameData($userId: User){
  user(userId:$userId){
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
query variables
{
  "userId" : 2
}
```

But i am getter error as : 
Variable \"$userId\" cannot be non-input type \"User
http://prntscr.com/h2ojor

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://prntscr.com/h2oop9

You have to specify datatype with ! this symbol to get the variables

```
query getUserNameData($userId: Int!) {
  user(userId: $userId) {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of how to have dynamic fields such as `firstName` or `lastName`?